# select2 не выводятся результаты при ajax поиске

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select2

Здравствуйте.

При поиске аяксом, не выводятся результаты. Во вкладке нетворк, все данные приходят, но select2 их не выводит почемуто.

```
jQuery('.js-select-search').select2({
        ajax: {
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 800,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                // alter the remote JSON data
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        language: "ru",
        minimumInputLength: 3
    });

<select name="parent_id" class="form-control js-select-search" data-ajax-url="{{ route('search-products') }}"><option value="0">Не выбран</option></select>
```

В контроллере

```
/**
 * Search products by name or sku
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function searchProducts(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json(Product::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')->orWhere('sku', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')->get(['name', 'id']));
}
```

Comment: Зачем контроллер? Лучше пример данных

Comment: Где HTML код разметки?

Comment: @Alex78191 разобрался уже) надо было в processResults циклом пройтись по данным. А разметка в самом низу блока с js кодом

Comment: Добавьте ответ на вопрос